# How to find nPr (permutations) efficiently?

Tags: math, permutation

Is there any better way than using the basic formula n!/(n-r)! like we have for nCr(combinations) nCr = (n-l)Cr + (n-1)C(r-1) ?

Comment: You need to define "better" more precisely.

Comment: Initially, the "better" method will be to write the simplest code and after you determine that isn't good enough then try to improve it.

Comment: I have already implemented the basic version. My question is if there is any other recursive formula for calculating permutations like we have for nCr in which we don't have to multiply a lot ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't the recursive function for nCr take an exponential amount of time to run?  Each level calls itself twice all the way down.  If you start combining levels together to avoid this then you end up multiplying stuff together.  Any speedup from only adding is quickly lost by how much more you actually have to add together for this formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this: ***nPr = (n−1)Pr + (n−1)P(r−1) ⋅ r***

Rationale: *nPr* denotes the number of ways to choose *r* elements from *n* while noting their order and not putting them back. In the above recursion I distinguish two cases. Either you don't choose the *n*th element, in which case you'll be choosing all your *r* elements from a set of *(n−1)*. Or you'll be choosing the *n*th element as well, in which case you'll be choosing the other *(r−1)* elements from a set of *(n−1)*, and there are *r* possibilities at what point in the order you chose that *n*th element.

Apart from this, also note that you can avoid the two factorials by taking the product only over the difference:

```
  n
─┬──┬─       n!
 │  │   i = ──── = (n−r+1)⋅(n−r+2)⋅…⋅(n−1)⋅n = nPr
 │  │        r!
i=n−r+1
```

This leads to yet another recursive formulation: ***nPr = (n−1)P(r−1) ⋅ n***

Comment: You should probably do this using a product tree --- in the nontrivial case, nPr = nP((n+r)/2) * ((n+r)/2)Pr.  You work with smaller numbers this way.

Comment: Please share range for n and r. Sharing the formula in a set format with ranges mentioned would be useful.